# How can the L1, L2, L3 CPU caches be turned off on modern x86/amd64 chips?

Tags: x86, intel, cpu-cache, memory-access, msr

Every modern high-performance CPU of the x86/x86_64 architecture has some hierarchy of data caches: L1, L2, and sometimes L3 (and L4 in very rare cases), and data loaded from/to main RAM is cached in some of them.

Sometimes the programmer may want some data to not be cached in some or all cache levels (for example, when wanting to memset 16 GB of RAM and keep some data still in the cache): there are some non-temporal (NT) instructions for this like MOVNTDQA  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092 http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/)

But is there a programmatic way (for some AMD or Intel CPU families like P3, P4, Core, Core i*, ...) to completely (but temporarily) turn off some or all levels of the cache, to change how every memory access  instruction (globally or for some applications / regions of RAM) uses the memory hierarchy? For example: turn off L1, turn off L1 and L2? Or change every memory access type to "uncached" UC (CD+NW bits of CR0??? SDM vol3a pages [423](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-423.html) [424](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-424.html), [425](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-425.html) and "*Third-Level Cache Disable flag, bit 6 of the IA32_MISC_ENABLE MSR (Available only in processors based on Intel NetBurst microarchitecture) — Allows the L3 cache to be disabled and enabled, independently of the L1 and L2 caches*.").

I think such action will help to protect data from cache side channel attacks/leaks like stealing AES keys, covert cache channels, Meltdown/Spectre. Although this disabling will have an enormous performance cost.

PS: I remember such a program posted many years ago on some technical news website, but can't find it now. It was just a Windows exe to write some magical values into an MSR and make every Windows program running after it very slow. The caches were turned off until reboot or until starting the program with the "undo" option.

Comment: Hello! Check "Disabling and Enabling the L3 Cache" (and around) and "MTRR" sections of the Intel SDM vol. 3a https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm - https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-429.html https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-428.html "*The third-level cache disable flag (bit 6 of the IA32_MISC_ENABLE MSR) allows the L3 
cache to be disabled and enabled, independently of the L1 and L2 caches*", and IA32_MISC_ENABLE, page 424 "Table 11-5. Cache Operating Modes" CD flag of CR0 reg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enable/disable cache on intel 64bit machine: CD bit always set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265785/enable-disable-cache-on-intel-64bit-machine-cd-bit-always-set) and [system becomes **extremely slow** after disable cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270356/). Also: Disabling cache was used to attack SGX enclave: Georgia/MS 2016 1611.06952v1 ["Inferring Fine-grained Control Flow Inside SGX Enclaves with Branch Shadowing"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06952) ["Disabling cache. If we want to attack .. short loop"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06952.pdf)

Comment: Also: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/disabling-cpu-caches-936077/ and memtest's `cache_on`/`cache_off` functions: https://github.com/vathpela/memtest86-/blob/master/test.h#L206; https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/278571 "*The caches may not be used but they are not disabled.*" and https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/737627 "*CR0.CD has a scope of "core".*". Also for partial disable: PCD "page-level cache disable (bit 4 of cr3)"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The Intel's manual 3A](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf), Section 11.5.3, provides an algorithm to *globally* disable the caches:

> **11.5.3 Preventing Caching**
>
> To disable the L1, L2, and L3 caches after they have been enabled and have received cache fills, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Enter the no-fill cache mode. (Set the CD flag in control register CR0 to 1 and the NW flag to 0.
> 2. Flush all caches using the WBINVD instruction.
> 3. Disable the MTRRs and set the default memory type to uncached or set all MTRRs for the uncached memory
>      type (see the discussion of the discussion of the TYPE field and the E flag in Section 11.11.2.1,
>      “IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE MSR”).
>
> The caches must be flushed (step 2) after the CD flag is set to ensure system memory coherency. If the caches are
>   not flushed, cache hits on reads will still occur and data will be read from valid cache lines.
>
> The intent of the three separate steps listed above addresses three distinct requirements: (i) discontinue new data
>   replacing existing data in the cache (ii) ensure data already in the cache are evicted to memory, (iii) ensure subsequent memory references observe UC memory type semantics. Different processor implementation of caching
>   control hardware may allow some variation of software implementation of these three requirements. See note below.
>
> **NOTES** 
>   Setting the CD flag in control register CR0 modifies the processor’s caching behaviour as indicated
>   in Table 11-5, but setting the CD flag alone may not be sufficient across all processor families to
>   force the effective memory type for all physical memory to be UC nor does it force strict memory
>   ordering, due to hardware implementation variations across different processor families. To force
>   the UC memory type and strict memory ordering on all of physical memory, it is sufficient to either
>   program the MTRRs for all physical memory to be UC memory type or disable all MTRRs.
>
> For the Pentium 4 and Intel Xeon processors, after the sequence of steps given above has been
>   executed, the cache lines containing the code between the end of the WBINVD instruction and
>   before the MTRRS have actually been disabled may be retained in the cache hierarchy. Here, to remove code from the cache completely, a second WBINVD instruction must be executed after the
>   MTRRs have been disabled.

That's a long quote but it boils down to this code

```
;Step 1 - Enter no-fill mode
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1<<30        ; Set bit CD
and eax, ~(1<<29)    ; Clear bit NW
mov cr0, eax

;Step 2 - Invalidate all the caches
wbinvd

;All memory accesses happen from/to memory now, but UC memory ordering may not be enforced still.  

;For Atom processors, we are done, UC semantic is automatically enforced.

xor eax, eax
xor edx, edx
mov ecx, IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE    ;MSR number is 2FFH
wrmsr

;P4 only, remove this code from the L1I
wbinvd
```

most of which is not executable from user mode.

---

[AMD's manual 2](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24593.pdf) provides a similar algorithm in section 7.6.2

> **7.6.2 Cache Control Mechanisms**
>   The AMD64 architecture provides a number of mechanisms for controlling the cacheability of memory. These are described in the following sections.
>
> **Cache Disable**. Bit 30 of the CR0 register is the cache-disable bit, CR0.CD. Caching is enabled
>   when CR0.CD is cleared to 0, and caching is disabled when CR0.CD is set to 1. When caching is
>   disabled, reads and writes access main memory.
>
> Software can disable the cache while the cache still holds valid data (or instructions). If a read or write
>   hits the L1 data cache or the L2 cache when CR0.CD=1, the processor does the following:
>
> 1. Writes the cache line back if it is in the modified or owned state.
> 2. Invalidates the cache line.
> 3. Performs a non-cacheable main-memory access to read or write the data.
>
> If an instruction fetch hits the L1 instruction cache when CR0.CD=1, some processor models may read
>   the cached instructions rather than access main memory. When CR0.CD=1, the exact behavior of L2
>   and L3 caches is model-dependent, and may vary for different types of memory accesses.
>
> The processor also responds to cache probes when CR0.CD=1. Probes that hit the cache cause the
>   processor to perform Step 1. Step 2 (cache-line invalidation) is performed only if the probe is
>   performed on behalf of a memory write or an exclusive read.
>
> **Writethrough Disable**. Bit 29 of the CR0 register is the not writethrough disable bit, CR0.NW. In
>   early x86 processors, CR0.NW is used to control cache writethrough behavior, and the combination of
>   CR0.NW and CR0.CD determines the cache operating mode.
>
> [...]
>
> In implementations of the AMD64 architecture, CR0.NW is not used to qualify the cache operating
>   mode established by CR0.CD.

This translates to this code (very similar to the Intel's one):

```
;Step 1 - Disable the caches
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1<<30
mov cr0, eax

;For some models we need to invalidated the L1I
wbinvd

;Step 2 - Disable speculative accesses
xor eax, eax
xor edx, edx
mov ecx, MTRRdefType  ;MSR number is 2FFH
wrmsr
```

---

Caches can also be selectively disabled at:

- Page level, with the attribute bits PCD (Page Cache Disable) [Only for Pentium Pro and Pentium II].
  When both are clear the MTTR of relevance is used, if PCD is set the aching
- Page level, with the PAT (Page Attribute Table) mechanism.
  By filling the `IA32_PAT` with caching types and using the bits PAT, PCD, PWT as a 3-bit index it's possible to select one the six caching types (UC-, UC, WC, WT, WP, WB).
- Using the MTTRs (fixed or variable).
  By setting the caching type to UC or UC- for specific *physical* areas.

Of these options only the page attributes can be exposed to user mode programs (see for example [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: So, PCD bit and MTTR disables all levels of cache? What about selective disabling? Will bit 6 of the IA32_MISC_ENABLE MSR disable only L3 keeping L1 and L2 online, is it documented? Is there usable linux kernel module source to test CR0.CD disabling?

Comment: @osgx Bit 6 of `IA32_MISC_ENABLE` should be present just in the Netburst arch (Pentium 4 and Xeons of the time). However, recent Xeons have the CAT (Cache Allocation Technology), described in Chapter 17.18, to assign chunks of the LLC to cores (including no chunks at all). The MTTRs disable all the caches (the processor doesn't even respond to snoops). The PCD bit does the same but due to page aliasing I'm not sure if hits go all the way to memory (I believe so, any line hitting should be invalidated on any access and eventually refilled when accessed from the aliasing page with cache enabled)

Comment: @osgx I'm not aware of any kernel module, but there is an example module [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654269/how-to-know-the-values-of-cr-registers-from-linux-user-and-kernel-modes/30731812#30731812). I see if I can turn it into a cache disabling module if you don't mind compiling.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Hi. I was trying to run your example and got this error "error: symbol `IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE' undefined". I tested it on Intel x86_64.

Comment: @Tigran84 You need to define `IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE`, I didn't because the code is meant to be a snippet. The comment also tells the MSR number, so you can either add `%define IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE 0x2ff` at the top of the code (if using NASM, other assemblers have different syntax) or replace `mov ecx, IA32_MTRR_DEF_TYPE` with `mov ecx, 0x2ff`. Same goes for the AMD code.