# Modify the write policy of the cache

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Current processors often use write-back cache. Is there any way to set the processor to use write-through cache? Or is there any way to disable the cache?
My purpose of doing this is to measure some experimental data. The cache write strategy has a great impact.

Comment: Yes, x86 for example has configurable cache modes with MTRR and/or PAT, including WT and disabled.  Some ARM CPUs, especially ones aimed at embedded systems, may have even more control over caching.

Comment: Can it be set to write-through mode?

Comment: Yes, that's what WT stands for.

Comment: Can write-through be set on a commonly used Intel CPU server?

Comment: Intel server CPUs implement the x86 ISA, so yes, google it.  ([When use write-through cache policy for pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61129142) might have some relevant links.)

Comment: If you're only interested in x86, seems like a duplicate of [How can the L1, L2, L3 CPU caches be turned off on modern x86/amd64 chips?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48360238)