# Is there a way to enable programmatically L1 L2 L3 caches using msr-tools on Linux?

Tags: linux, intel, cpu-registers, cpu-cache, msr

We have a server with Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6338N CPU @ 2.20GHz.

For this server the L1, L2, L3 caches seem not enabled...

Is there a way to check the CPU registers with msr tools (rdmsr/wrmsr) on Linux
to see if the caches are enabled and optionally to enable/disable them ?

What are the relevant registers?

The problem is.... I found only relevant information on the CPU register CR0 for the CD bit, but the register CR0 can be accessed only from ring 0 (i.e. only from the kernel), instead my question is if there is the possibility to access registers relevant to the caches from ring 3 (i.e. user space).

Comment: I think that linked duplicate ([How can the L1, L2, L3 CPU caches be turned off on modern x86/amd64 chips?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48360238)) covers Intel's documentation on the MSR numbers; it shows asm to disable cache (after using `wbinvd` to drain it, not 100% sure that's necessary).  The same MSR could be read.  I might have been a bit hasty since you're asking about using msr-tools from the command line, as well as which MSRs are relevant.

Comment: I think my question is still relevant and not a duplicate... I found that info enable/disable for the caches is in the cpu register cr0, but that can be accessed only by the kernel as it is in ring 0... and I didn't found any viable alternative from ring 3....

Comment: Well obviously not from ring3 alone; msr-tools makes a system call to ask the kernel (ring 0) to run a `wrmsr` or `rdmsr` instruction (e.g. read or write on `/dev/cpu/*/msr`).  A similar kernel module is needed to let user-space ask for it to modify bits in control registers.