# How to turn off the level 3 cache on my AMD Threadripper Pro so I can get good benchmarking of my Gnu C++ code?

Tags: caching, x86-64, benchmarking

I want to run some benchmarks on my C++ code and I think that the level 3 cache, in particular, will cause the numbers to be difficult to interpret. I'm happy to modify
the code to make the cache turn off under Linux (Debian stable) but I've never had to mess with that stuff, so I'm asking you folks...

My data structures grow in the course of running the program, but only to a limited extent. I'm expecting that I can get some idea of the limits of execution time for real inputs by turning off the L3 cache and characterizing program behavior.

Graeme.

Comment: Wouldn't those numbers be meaningless? Who else that would run your code would do the same?

Comment: On the contrary, what I'm looking for is confirmation (or denial) of the algorithm's computational complexity in time and space. I can instrument the code to measure its space complexity, but the code will probably make the L3 cache thrash at some point. By removing the L3 cache from the picture, I will get at most a constant factor of slowdown, but the execution times will be comparable over a much larger span of input sizes. I plan to plot the data and run some statistics on it.  - Cheers, Graeme.

Comment: Yeah, that might work to let you microbenchmark the "cold L3" case while still using a tight repeat loop, if your data is typically too large to hit in L1d / L2, and your real use-case will run lots of code between calls, or loops over big arrays.  Branch prediction will still be fully dedicated to your microbenchmark, unlike as part of bigger program, but a lot of code predicts well even in real use-cases.

Comment: But I'm not sure if there is a way to disable L3 while leaving L1d / L2 enabled on AMD.  On Intel almost certainly not, on CPUs where the tags of inclusive L3 are used as a coherency directory for MESI states.  [How can the L1, L2, L3 CPU caches be turned off on modern x86/amd64 chips?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48360238) describes how to disable all caches on Intel or AMD with the CD (Cache Disable) bit in CR0, but that wouldn't be useful; at least L1d cache is absolutely essential for realistic performance.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I followed that last link and found mention of a potential solution. It may not be possible to selectively turn off the L3 cache but it seems to imply that disabling the caches can be done by flipping a bit in a register.  I'll have to renew my acquaintance with AMD's tech website and get their manual(s).  I don't really care how much of a slowdown there is, as long as I get a wide spread of input sizes and consistent execution times. :-)